# curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org Certificate issue on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ssl, composer-php, certificate

I've installed composer globally (and locally - just for testing) according to https://getcomposer.org/download/

Then, I'm trying `composer create-project laravel/laravel` and I receive an error:

> composer create-project laravel/laravel
> Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./laravel"
>
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
> curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json:
> SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'repo.packagist.org'

So I've tried this one including the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59339136/2110476

```
curl.cainfo = "/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile = "/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"
openssl.capath = "/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"
```

into the 7.4 CLI php.ini: `php --ini`

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
> Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
> Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
> Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
> ...

which seems to be fine? `php -i | grep -i openssl`

> SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.1.1f
> libSSH Version => libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib
> openssl
> OpenSSL support => enabled
> OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
> OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
> Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
> openssl.cafile => /home/hpn/Software/cacert.pem => /home/hpn/Software/cacert.pem
> openssl.capath => /home/hpn/Software/cacert.pem => /home/hpn/Software/cacert.pem
> Native OpenSSL support => enabled

I've even gone so far and tried [Composer Require 'package' throws OpenSSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51553826/composer-require-package-throws-openssl-error)

```
composer config disable-tls true
composer config secure-http false
```

But the error still remains.

Then I've found this one: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html
and did: `sudo  update-ca-certificates` - still with the same error.

Comment: What version of composer are you using?

Comment: Composer version 2.0.14 2021-05-21 17:03:37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a static IP set in my `/etc/hosts` file.
After I've commented that one out, things worked as expected.

Sorry for the confusion - maybe it'll still help someone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you: downloading the cert and updating the php.ini values didn't work.

I simply upgraded all my server packages `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and the problem was solved. I haven't pinpointed yet what the exact package/packages need to be updated though.

Answer (score 1):

just simply go to your command prompt if you are windows type the following command

```
 "composer config --global -- disable-tls false"  (windows)
 "composer config --global disable-tls false" (linux)
```

i think it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Firewall, proxy or general networking related. Retry

[image]